# Link to the review task that deleted an answer on the answer itself

Tags: feature-request, review, deleted-answers

For a while, we've had an entry in revision history when a /review queue deletes a post. This is great:

[image: this is good]

However, it's inconvenient to get to the revision history on some posts without revision history, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018095/1849664):

[image: this is bad]

I had to manually construct the link to get to it. I do not like this. How about this?

[image]